# Prime Factors using Erathosthenes sieve

Tags: c, prime-factoring

Trying to print the prime factors of a number using Erathosthenes sieve instead of finding the factors and then checking whether each factor is a prime number.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<math.h>

void primeFactors(int num)
{
    int factors[100];

    int i,j=0,u,k=0,l;
    u=sqrt(num);

    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
        factors[i]=1;

    for(i=2;i<=u;i++)
    {
        if(factors[i]==0)
            continue;

        if(num%i==0)
        {
            factors[j]=i;
            l=factors[j];
            k=2*factors[j];
            j++;

            while(k<=u)
            {
                if(factors[k]==0)
                    continue;
                factors[k]=0;
                k+=l;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=2;i<=u;i++)
        if(factors[i]!=1)
            printf("%d\n",factors[i]);

}

int main()
{
    int n=797;
    primeFactors(n);
    return 0;
}
```

On running it on Xcode it neither shows any error nor prints a single thing. I can't figure out the issue . Why isn't this printing? 
Thanks.

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, and then construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth - Thanks. I have tried using the debugger but it immediately switches to assembly view and adding print statements wasn't of much help either.

Comment: Appropriate print statements should allow you to trace exactly where your program is going, and why it's making various decisions.  You then use that information by comparing it to what you *expected* to happen.  That is what debugging is.

Comment: Advice taken and thankyou:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part:

```
while(k<=u)
{
    if(factors[k]==0)
        continue;
```

looks a lot like an infinite loop.

Comment: Indeed.  But by answering, you've caused the OP not to invest the time into learning debugging techniques :(

Comment: We could apply that logic to almost any question. It's not the only thing wrong here anyway.

Comment: We could definitely apply that logic to a *lot* of questions, yes!  But in general, any question of the form "where is the error in my code?  I haven't debugged" gets an immediate close-vote from me...

Comment: @JasonD Thanks. Thanks also for the hint that there are many more bugs in the code.